# List not updating new object in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am pushing a new object in the array but couldn't see the new value updated on UI. I am using angular js here and updating a value. here is my code.

**html**

```
<ul  id="list-wrapper-noti" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right style-3" >
    <div infinite-scroll-disabled = "disableScroll" infinite-scroll='loadMoreNotifications()' infinite-scroll-distance='0' infinite-scroll-container="'#list-wrapper-noti'">
      <li >
          <a href="list.php?id=20" style=" color:#3C71C1; padding-top: 3px">See all </a>
          <a class="pull-right" href="list.php?id=20" style=" color:#3C71C1;">Mark all as read </a>
     </li>
    <li style="height: 30px"></li>


   <li ng-repeat = "notification in notifications track by $index">
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#534D4D" href="{{notification.href}}" >
         <div class="media">

     <img src="https://papa.fit/routes/images/inst_logo/default.png" alt="fakeimg" class="img-circle pull-left" style="height:50px; width:50px;">

      <div class="media-body">
      <div class="media">{{notification.employee}} {{notification.action | lowercase}} {{notification.element}} {{notification.record_value}}</div>
          <span class="muted">{{notification.time_string}}</span>
       </div>

       </div>
    </a>
  <div class="divider"></div>
 </li>
```

**controller**

```
function addNewNotification(new_noti){
      var obj = {"action":new_noti.data.action,"element":new_noti.data.element,"record_value":new_noti.data.record_value,"time_string":new_noti.data.time_string,"employee":new_noti.data.employee};
      $scope.notifications.unshift(obj);
      console.log($scope.notifications)

  }
```

**and from here I am calling this func**

```
angular.element('#list-wrapper-noti').scope().addNewNotification(payload);
```

I don't know why it is not getting updated after push in array.please anyone help ?

Comment: does your log  (console.log($scope.notifications) appears?

Comment: what is payload?

Comment: yes @Faly. I got new obj in array and printed on console as well.

Comment: payload is an object coming from FCM @Dixit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject $timeout into your controller and try this:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.notifications.unshift(obj);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Faly. you made my day.